# Angular 5: Is there easy way check if background image is dead and then use default image instead?

Tags: angular

In angular 2+, in template `<img>` tag we do something like this: `<img [src]="myDp" (error)="myDp='assets/media/user/default_dp.jpg'">`, where `myDp` has relative path to image on server. Now is there way to similar thing to image that is being used in inline css `background-image`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just append multiple images to the `background-image` property so if the last one fails the previous will be used. Example:

```css
background-image: url('assets/fallbackimage.jpg'), url('some/image/url/that/might/fail');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'image()' notation if I'm not mistaken. Like this:

```
background-image: image("wavy.svg", 'wavy2.png');
```

If the first one is broken, the second one will be displayed. Could you check if this works?